# Regular Expression remove leading blank and dash character

Tags: regex

Given a string like `String a="- = - - What is your name?";`

How to remove the leading equal, dash, space characters, to get the clean text,

> "What is your name?"

Comment: what language are you working in?

Comment: All answers here right now are correct, some are more strict other more liberal in what they remove from the string. Different languages also have slightly differing implementations/syntax for their regexes. So you'll have to be very specific with regards to language and requirements of your regex to get the 'best' answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to remove the leading non-alphabets you can match:

```
^[^a-zA-Z]+
```

and replace it with `''` (empty string).

Explanation:

- `first ^` - Anchor to match at the
  begining.
- `[]` - char class
- `second ^` - negation in a char class
- `+` - One or more of the previous match

So the regex matches *one or more of any non-alphabets that are at the beginning of the string.*

In your case case it will get rid of all the leading spaces, leading hyphens and leading equals sign. In short everything before the first alphabet.

Comment: ^\W+ generally does the same, maybe change the + into * (there might be nothing preceding)

Comment: @NomenN: \W does not include digits, but [^a-zA-Z] can include digits. replacing + with * is not a good idea, say input is "Hi there" where I don't need to replace anything. But if I use * I'll still have a match (empty match) and I'll replace it with empty sting...resulting in no change. Using + will not match anything so nothing to replace...making it more efficient..preformance. wise.

Comment: I guess the digits part depends upon the requirements. Good explanation on the * vs +, I hadn't considered that.

Comment: Thanks @codaddict, I don't want any digital. Your explanation is very clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $a=~s/- = - - //;
```

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript you could do it like this

```
var a = "- = - - What is your name?";
a = a.replace(/^([-=\s]*)([a-zA-Z0-9])/gm,"$2");
```

Comment: Why not just `a.replace(/^[-=\s]*/mg, "")`

Comment: My background thought was that he might not want this to work on blank lines, but your assumption set could also be right.

Answer (score 1):

Java:

```
String replaced = a.replaceFirst("^[-= ]*", "");
```

Comment: @NomeN: Why? If none of the offending characters are present--oh wait, I see @codaddict has already covered this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Java try this regex:

```
 /^\W*(.*)$/
```

retrieve your string from captured group 1!

`\W*` matches all preceding non-word characters
`(.*)`then matches all characters to the end beginning with the first word character

^,$ are the boundaries. you could even do without $ in this case.

Tip try the excellent [Java regex tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

In Python:

```
>>> "- = - - What is your name?".lstrip("-= ")
'What is your name?'
```

To remove any kind of whitespace, use `.lstrip("-= \t\r\n")`.

Comment: Nope. `lstrip` takes a list of characters, not a regex.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, I needed to do this and did it using the following regex:

```
^[\s\-]+
```

and replace it with '' (empty string) like this:

```
yourStringValue.replace(/^[\s\-]+/, '');
```